# Why is Jenkins saying "No artifacts found" when every single file should fit the criteria?

Tags: jenkins

I set up a simple jenkins server to compile custom Android ROMs for my phone. However, when archiving the build ROM, Jenkins is unable to find the files.

I've tried getting broader and broader with the criteria, ultimately putting just '*.*' in the archive options but it still finds no files.

This is my script for copying the files to the workspace directory for archiving.

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 - Build number
# $2 - Workspace Directory
# $3 - Device
# $4 - Build Directory

cd /var/lib/jenkins/android/"$4"/out/target/product/"$3"

for z in *.zip; do
    if [[ "${z}" != *"ota"* ]]; then
        echo cp "$z" "$2/${z%.zip}-$1.zip"
    fi
done

echo cp boot.img "$2/boot-$1.img"
```

These are the related messages when the script is run.

```
+ /var/lib/jenkins/copy_artifacts.sh 17 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LineageOS/j7popltespr j7popltespr lineage
cp lineage-16.0-20190715-UNOFFICIAL-j7popltespr.zip /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LineageOS/j7popltespr/lineage-16.0-20190715-UNOFFICIAL-j7popltespr-17.zip
cp lineage-16.0-20190716-UNOFFICIAL-j7popltespr.zip /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LineageOS/j7popltespr/lineage-16.0-20190716-UNOFFICIAL-j7popltespr-17.zip
cp boot.img /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LineageOS/j7popltespr/boot-17.img
Archiving artifacts
‘*.*’ doesn’t match anything
ERROR: Step ‘Archive the artifacts’ failed: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "*.*". Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. `echo cp` doesn't actually copy the files. I've switched it to `cp -v`.